# How can I shorten or clean up this python code?

Tags: python, refactoring

I had a homework assignment to write a program that takes a highway number as input and outputs whether the highway is primary or auxiliary, goes east/west, north/south, and if it is auxiliary, what primary highway is it serving. Here is my code, which awarded me full credit, but I'm a beginner and there has to be a shorter way to write it. Would someone mind cleaning this up?

```
highway_number = int(input())

if highway_number >= 1 and highway_number <= 99:
    prim = 'is primary,'
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('The', highway_number, prim, 'going east/west.')
    else:
        print('The', highway_number, prim, 'going north/south.')
elif highway_number >= 100 and highway_number <= 999:
    aux = 'is auxiliary,'
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('The', highway_number, aux, 'serving the %d, going east/west.' % (highway_number%100))
    else:
        print('The', highway_number, aux, 'serving the %d, going north/south.' % (highway_number%100))
else:
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

Here, 290 outputs:

```
The 290 is auxiliary, serving the 90, going east/west.
```

Comment: Requests for improvements to working code should be posted to codereview.stackexchange.com; be sure to read their [posting guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of

1) Chained comparisons

2) f-strings

3) in-line if-statements utilizing the boolean-ness of 0/1

Makes the code much shorter

```
highway_number = int(input())

if 1 <= highway_number <= 99:
    direction = 'east/west' if highway_number % 2 else 'north/south'
    print(f'The {highway_number} is primary, going {direction}')
elif 100 <= highway_number <= 999:
    direction = 'north/south' if highway_number % 2 else 'east/west'
    print(f'The {highway_number} is auxiliary, serving the {highway_number%100}, going {direction}')
else:
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```